# Regular expression for grep to extract lines with exact ocurrences of a symbol

Tags: regex, text, grep

Having a text data file containing [SMILES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) strings like these:

```
CN1CCC2OC(C)(CO)C3=C(NN=C3)N=C12
BrC1=CC(=O)N2C=NC(CC(=O)C#N)=CC2=C1
```

how it would be a regular expression to extract the lines containing only 4 carbon atoms, meaning 4 Cs and no other capital letter, while numbers, parenthesis, `=` and `#` are allowed.

Update:

1. small C is also allowed, then 4 Cs or cs
2. `grep -E '([^C]*C){4}' filename` extracts lines with at least 4 Cs
3. square brackets, `-` and `@` must be also discarded
4. check out some examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/m2Kkso/1)

Comment: `^([^A-Z]*C){4}[^A-Z]*$`

Comment: Which shown line fulfills the requirement to contain only 4 C?

Comment: I don't think most readers will understand your question. I suggest you provide, say, four example lines, with two meeting the requirement and two not meeting the requirement, with you explaining why each line does or does not meet the requirement. Perhaps underline the "C"'s (or "c"'s) that are to be counted.

Comment: Should `C3` be counted as 3 carbon atoms? And as the letter "c" or "C" in included in the elements `C`, `Cl`, `Ca`, `Sc`, `Cr`, `Co`, `Cu`, `Tc`, `Cd`, `Cs`, `Cn`, `Mc`, `Ce`, `Ac`, `Cm`, `Cf`, I would be more precise and say that it should match "C" not followed by one of these lowercase letters or a "c" not prefixed by some specific capitals: `C(?![laroudsnemf])|(?<![STMA])c`

Comment: **What about other allowed chars** such as `[`, `]`, `$`, `+`, `-`, `@`, etc ? And my question: *"is it possible to have a molecule made of only 4 carbon atoms?"*. I would have thought that you would need other atoms to create a stable molecule.

Comment: @nightcod3r -- question: if lowercase c is allowed, how do you know if something like `cs` is Carbon-Sulfur or Cesium, or `sc` is Sulfur-Carbon or Scandium? Things become ambiguous if you allow both small and upper c for an element for the above reason.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right, examples added...

Comment: @PatrickJanser agreed, square brackets might also be part of the string for a particular type on caninization. Also, `-` and `@`, not sure about `+` and `$`.

Comment: @PatrickJanser also agreed in the C followed by a lowercase (other than `c`).

Comment: @David542 It's a good question. The thing is that `c` is the SMILES notation for carbons forming cyclic rings only, not sure if sulfur can be part of these rings.

Comment: @nightcod3r I see, thanks for the answer. I think this is at the border of what a regex is capable of doing. I think as soon as you get into things like `C3` counting as 3 carbon atoms, or allowing lowercase in certain areas, the complexity and length of the regex would go up exponentially, if it can handle it at all, and you need to have a more sophisticated approach such as a parser.

Comment: Which from the examples that you posted should and should not match? You want to use grep to match the whole line right? is `grep -P` supported?

Answer (score 1):

#### First thoughts

I thought about my suggestions in the comments, using some negative
lookaheads and lookbehinds, but it's often not handled by some regex engines.

So we'll forget `C(?![laroudsnemf])|(?<![STMA])c` which was used to
match carbon with a lowercase version for rings. It would have worked
with `grep -P` to enable the *PCRE* engine, but I prefer avoiding it.

But this can be replaced by **setting up a pattern that will consume
the other elements in the same time as the ignored characters**:

- According to
  [Wikipedia's page about SMILES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system),
  the ignored chars list is quite big, leading to "-", "+", ".", "=",
  "#", "$", "@", "(", ")", "[", "]", "/", "\", ":", "%". We finally
  get this pattern : `[-+.=#$@()\[\]\/\\:%0-9]`
- All 2-chars elements starting with a "C": `C[laroudsnemf]`
- All 2-chars elements finishing with a "c": `[STMA]c`
- Any single-char element but not "C": `[HBNOFPSKVYIWU]`
- Any other 2-chars element without "C" or "c": `[ABD-Z][abd-z]`
  Here we are clearly not very precise, as some combinations of
  upper and lowercase chars won't be existing elements. Never mind,
  it should not be a problem.

**Edit**: thanks to the comment of @David542, he saw that "Sc"
wasn't detected as the scandium element, but "S" was taken for
sulphur and then "c" as the carbon (in a ring). To solve that, I
finally forced the pattern to be possessive (greedy) by replacing
the `*` by `*+`.

#### Setting up the pattern

- I'll use the **x** flag in order to add some comments in the
  pattern.
- I don't want to copy-paste or repeat patterns, so I'll use
  sub-patterns which I will name, in order to make things clear.
  This can be done with the help of named capturing groups
  `(?<group_name>...)` where `...` is your pattern.
- In *PCRE*, you can use the `(?(DEFINE)...)` construct to declare
  sub-patterns without using them. It's like creating functions for
  a later use.

Putting it all together:

```
/
(?(DEFINE)

  # Match a carbon atom only. It can be a uppercase "C" or lowercase
  # "c" (for rings). We'll avoid negative lookahead and lookbehind and
  # instead let the "ignored" pattern consume these other elements.
  (?<carbon>[cC])

  # Ignored other elements and syntax chars.
  # This pattern should be greedy with *+ instead of *. This will make
  # the pattern consume "Sc" or "Tc" so that we cannot match the "c"
  # as a carbon atom. This solution is to avoid using negative lookbehind
  # and lookahead inside the carbon sub-pattern just above.
  (?<ignored>
    (?:                  # Non-capturing just for the "or" operator.
      [-+.=\#$@()\[\]\/\\:%0-9] # ignored chars.
      |
      C[laroudsnemf]     # Cx Elements: Cl, Ca, Cr, Co, Cu, etc
      |
      [STMA]c            # Xc Elements: Sc, Tc, Mc and Ac
      |
      [HBNOFPSKVYIWU]    # Any single-letter element, but not C.
      |
      [ABD-Z][abd-z]     # 2-chars Elements (not very precise but short)
    )*+                  # The ignored items can be 0 or n times, in a possessive way.
  )

)

# The pattern is carbon surounded by ignored elements and chars, 4 times.
^(?:\g<ignored>\g<carbon>\g<ignored>){4}$

/gmx
```

In action: https://regex101.com/r/88zReK/4

If you need to remove the comments to use it with *grep*, here's the
compressed version where backslashes have to be escaped to create
a correct string to pass to *grep*:

```
grep -P "(?(DEFINE)(?<carbon>[cC])(?<ignored>(?:[-+.=#$@()\\[\\]/\\\\:%0-9]|C[laroudsnemf]|[STMA]c|[HBNOFPSKVYIWU]|[ABD-Z][abd-z])*+))^(?:\\g<ignored>\\g<carbon>\\g<ignored>){4}$"
```

If you need to reproduce the compact pattern again, you can
use [a tool I made for my personal use on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/patacra/full/wvQBxjq).

#### EDIT: wrong final thoughts and POC to solve also the meaning of digits

<del>Personally, I would not ignore numbers as "CH2" means two
hydrogen atoms, so why not trying to handle something like
"C4" ? I don't even know if this is possible or not, but I
think it's worth trying to handle it.</del>

**This was a wrong assumption**! Numbers after "C" are not the
number of atoms like it's the case for "H2". It's the label of the
ring. So **the PHP code below to replace "C4" by "CCCC" is totally
worthless**. I'll just leave it here because it might be helpful for
other users having to process some data with a bit more power than
the simple usage of *grep* :

```php
<?php

const INPUT_FILE = 'smiles_input.txt';

// Read all the file in one go into an array of lines. If the file is too large,
// you'll have to open it and read it line by line to avoid running out of memory.
// We will also get rid of attached new line chars at the end of each line.
$input_lines = file(INPUT_FILE, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// A pattern to match only carbon elements, in upper or lowercase, followed by
// a number. We use negative lookbehind and lookahead to avoid matching other
// elements containing the letter "C" or "c".
const PATTERN_C_AND_NUMBER = '/(?<carbon>C(?![laroudsnemf])|(?<![STMA])c)(?<number>\d+)/';

// The pattern to match a molecule containing 4 carbon elements.
// I use Nowdoc string format to avoid having to escape everything.
const PATTERN_4_C_MOLECULE = <<<'END_OF_STRING'
/
(?(DEFINE)

  # Match a carbon atom only. It can be a uppercase "C" or lowercase
  # "c" (for rings). We'll avoid negative lookahead and lookbehind and
  # instead let the "ignored" pattern consume these other elements.
  (?<carbon>[cC])

  # Ignored other elements and syntax chars.
  # This pattern should be greedy with *+ instead of *. This will make
  # the pattern consume "Sc" or "Tc" so that we cannot match the "c"
  # as a carbon atom. This solution is to avoid using negative lookbehind
  # and lookahead inside the carbon sub-pattern just above.
  (?<ignored>
    (?:                  # Non-capturing just for the "or" operator.
      [-+.=\#$@()\[\]\/\\:%0-9] # ignored chars.
      |
      C[laroudsnemf]     # Cx Elements: Cl, Ca, Cr, Co, Cu, etc
      |
      [STMA]c            # Xc Elements: Sc, Tc, Mc and Ac
      |
      [HBNOFPSKVYIWU]    # Any single-letter element, but not C.
      |
      [ABD-Z][abd-z]     # 2-chars Elements (not very precise but short)
    )*+                  # The ignored items can be 0 or n times, in a greedy way.
  )

)

# The pattern is carbon surounded by ignored elements and chars, 4 times.
^(?:\g<ignored>\g<carbon>\g<ignored>){4}$

/x
END_OF_STRING;

foreach ($input_lines as $line_nbr => $molecula) {
    // Replace all occurrences of C followed by a number, by the C char repeated
    // the correct number of times. Ex: "C4" will be replaced by "CCCC".
    $changed_molecula = preg_replace_callback(
        PATTERN_C_AND_NUMBER,
        function ($matches) {
            return str_repeat($matches['carbon'], (int)$matches['number']);
        },
        $molecula
    );
    
    // Check if the molecula has only 4 carbon elements.
    if (preg_match(PATTERN_4_C_MOLECULE, $changed_molecula)) {
        print ($line_nbr + 1) . ": " . $molecula . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Run it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/6f062

Comment: what a fantastic answer! Great to see this kind of deep thought and time in a SO answer. My only open question is with the introduction of lowercase c something like `ScCCC` would match with the pattern above (I think I'd probably need to know more about the SMILES notation to offer a suggestion here).

Comment: @David542 Thanks a lot! Oh yes, stupid me, I didn't even check it correctly! Ideally, we should remove `[ABD-Z]` from the ignored chars and replace it by the exact list of all the elements. This way, both "S" and "c" from "Sc" would be consummed. Or if not, we should use the negative lookahead and lookbehind I had initially thought using. I'll have a try. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @David542 Well, moving `[ABD-Z]` down and `[STMA]c` up didn't seem to be enough. But I found how to solve it: we have to make the *ignored* pattern greedy by replacing `*` by `*+`. This way, "Sc" is consumed before the *carbon* pattern could eventually match the "c". I'll update the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickJanser please, note that numbers in a SMILE string (other that those following an `H`) are used for cycles (bonds shared by several atoms), and then `C4` would mean that the carbon atom bonds another atom with the same label.

Comment: @nightcod3r Oh yes, I just read Wikipedia’s page again, and I now see what you mean with the ring labels. So, effectively, my assumption was wrong as it’s different depending on the atom preceding the number. Well, in this case, simply forget my last part with the PHP script to replace these numbers. Hope I helped you, in any case.

Comment: @nightcod3r I've edited my answer to mention this wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy within your constraints.

> *"4 Cs and no other capital letter ..."*

Yet, the provided *regex101.com* examples all include additional capital letters—so, none of those will match.

The following will match when there are no other capital letters.

If you're looking to match, *exactly* 4

```
(?i)^(?:[^C]*C){4}[^C]*$
```

If you're looking to match, *at least*, 4, use the following.

```
(?i)^(?:[^C]*C){4,}[^C]*$
```

And, if you're looking to match, *at most*, 4, use this

```
(?i)^(?:[^C]*C){1,4}[^C]*$
```

Comment: that doesn't work on any of the sample inputs from the question.

Comment: @David542, I was using this constraint, _"4 Cs and no other capital letter"_, which I am now realizing is most likely incorrect.  I've update the patterns.

Answer (score -1):

This is such a wonderful question and reminds me of taking chemistry classes in high school. This is trickier than it seems. Conceptually, here is what we want to do:

- We want to capture: a `C` that is not followed by a lowercase letter. This must be captured exactly 4 times.
- And we want to skip any (a) numbers, (b) the punctuation `#`, `=`, `(`, and `)`, (c) any uppercase letter except `C` (such as `F`), (d) Any uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase letters (such as `Ca` or `Fe`).

If we convert it into a regex we have:

- Capture: `(C(?![a-z]))`
- Skip: `[#=()\dABD-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]`

Putting it all together with anchors and repetitions we get the following.

- [`^(?:[#=()\dABD-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])*(C(?![a-z]))(?:[#=()\dABD-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])*\1(?:[#=()\dABD-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])*\1(?:[#=()\dABD-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])*\1(?:[#=()\dABD-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])*$`](https://regex101.com/r/j261Zh/1)

[image]

Obviously there's a lot of copy-paste here, and other than using `\1` to repeat the `C`, I don't see a way to simplify this regex too much more in a non-trivial sense.

---

Updated with the following changes you asked for in the Skip condition: `[`, `]`, `-`, and `@` allowed.

- [`^(?:[#=()[\]\dABD-Z@-]|[A-Z][a-z])*(C(?![a-z]))(?:[#=()[\]\dABD-Z@-]|[A-Z][a-z])*\1(?:[#=()[\]\dABD-Z@-]|[A-Z][a-z])*\1(?:[#=()[\]\dABD-Z@-]|[A-Z][a-z])*\1(?:[#=()[\]\dABD-Z@-]|[A-Z][a-z])*$`](https://regex101.com/r/XPgehc/1)

[image]

And updated with the simplification suggested by @Patrick (thank you!) to use `\g` for the captured pattern. Note this pattern does not address: (a) lowercase-C for carbon; or (b) multipliers in atoms, such as `C4` to mean `CCCC`:

- [`^((?<ignored>(?:[#=()[\]\dABD-Z@-]|[A-Z][a-z])*)(?<carbon>C(?![a-z]))){4}\g<ignored>$`](https://regex101.com/r/98OC0U/1)

[image]

Comment: Looks like it will need some more refinement. After adding squared brackets (they also can be part of a SMILES string), this solutions doesn't seem to work. See examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/FaU7KD/1).

Comment: @nightcod3r I updated the answer, for the brackets you have to escape the right-bracket when inside a character class, otherwise it will end it. For example, if we want the character class of "a", "b", and "]" it would be: `[ab\]]` and not `[ab]]`, which would be evaluated as the character class `[ab]` followed by `]`.

Comment: I would just notify that `\1` is a back reference to the first capturing group, meaning that if you have `[CH]=[c-c-c]` (probably not a possible molecule, but just as an example) then the `\1` is equal to "C", which isn't equal to "c". So what you can do is name the capturing group with `(?<carbon> ... )` and then use `\g<carbon>` to re-use the same pattern and not the captured string (which can be done with `\k<carbon>` instead of `\g<carbon>`). Example: https://regex101.com/r/oyxh2f/1

Comment: @PatrickJanser updated with your suggestion, thank you! (Although kept out the lowercase-c). Your answer is much more comprehensive and agile than mine.

Comment: The arbitrary captures are not needed.  This can slow down a regular expression engine if it's iterating a multitude of values.